# How to find total CPU utilisation in java using Sigar

Tags: java, cpu-usage, sigar

I am trying to find a few system statistics (CPU Utilisation%, Disk Utilisation% and Memory Utilisation%) through a Java program. For this purpose I have been using SIGAR. Although (I think) I am getting the latter two correct, I am not getting the CPU Utilisation% correct. Appending my code below, can someone help me understand what is going wrong here?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuTimer;
import org.hyperic.sigar.DiskUsage;
import org.hyperic.sigar.FileSystemUsage;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Mem;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;




public class SystemMonitor {

    private static Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

    public static void getSystemStatistics(){
        Mem mem = null;
        CpuTimer cputimer = null;
        FileSystemUsage filesystemusage = null;
        try {
            mem = sigar.getMem();
            cputimer = new CpuTimer(sigar);
            filesystemusage = sigar.getFileSystemUsage("C:");          
        } catch (SigarException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.print(mem.getUsedPercent()+"\t");
        System.out.print(cputimer.getCpuUsage()+"\t");
        System.out.print(filesystemusage.getUsePercent()+"\n");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SystemMonitor m1 = new SystemMonitor();
        for(int i=0; i<1000;i++){
        m1.getSystemStatistics();   
        }
    }




}
```

I am getting a CPUUtilisation % of 0 consistently, which I think is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was interpreting CpuTimer incorrectly. I could find the CPU utilisation by using CpuPerc instead. Appending the code snippet:

```
public static void getSystemStatistics(){
    Mem mem = null;
    CpuPerc cpuperc = null;
    FileSystemUsage filesystemusage = null;
    try {
        mem = sigar.getMem();
        cpuperc = sigar.getCpuPerc();
        filesystemusage = sigar.getFileSystemUsage("C:");          
    } catch (SigarException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.print(mem.getUsedPercent()+"\t");
    System.out.print((cpuperc.getCombined()*100)+"\t");
    System.out.print(filesystemusage.getUsePercent()+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote something like this and it works great you can look it and find whats needed for your code. Note : Dont forget to start thread ^^

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        while (true) {
                                            /*
                                             * Memory of System
                                             */
                                            long actualFree = mem.getActualFree() / 1024
                                                    / 1024;
                                            long actualUsed = mem.getActualUsed() / 1024
                                                    / 1024;
                                            long per1Mem = (actualFree + actualUsed) / 100;
                                            system.out.println((((int) actualFree / per1Mem) * 1.0) / 100);
                                            /*
                                             * Disk Space
                                             */
                                            File file = new File("/");
                                            long totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace() / 1024 / 1024;
                                            long freeSpace = file.getUsableSpace() / 1024 / 1024;
                                            long per1Disk = totalSpace / 100;
                                            system.out.println(((int) freeSpace / per1Disk) * 1.0) / 100);
                                            /*
                                             * CPU USAGE
                                             */
                                            try {
                                                thread.sleep(1000); //needed for finding proper cpu usage
                                                CpuPerc perc = sigar.getCpuPerc();
                                                system.out.println(perc.getCombined());
                                            } catch (SigarException | InterruptedException e) {
                                                System.out.println("SigarException in CPU or InterruptedException!");
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```